# How to visit Canada for tourism

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada

I'm from India & I want to visit Canada as a tourist. I'll be staying in Quebec only. I have a few people (my mentors) to meet in Quebec. I want to stay for 6 months as a tourist and learn Canadian culture (mostly French). I have a few friends in Quebec, so accommodation will not be a problem. They can sponsor and write sponsorship letter for me so I don't have to pay for hotel & food. I'll be staying & eating with them.

How much money do I have to show in bank for visa & for how long I have to show the money in bank to get a 6 months visa?

Comment: Six months isn't really "visiting for tourism".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you can't even visit a city completely(visits churches, meet communities) in a month. So, six month's time provided as a tourist by Canadian Govt is justified.

Comment: I mean it's less than six months. So it's written almost 6 months on website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the "Visit Canada" web site...

(after answering a few questions)

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp?lnktrk=visa_less_six_months

For the money part, I did not find specific answer, I assume it is really dependent on the individual; the internet says about $5000 to $10000, depending on your lifestyle.

=======

> Basic travel requirements
> You must meet some basic requirements to travel to Canada. You must:
>
> - have a valid travel document, like a passport
> - be in good health
> - have no criminal or immigration-related convictions
> - convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country
> - convince an immigration officer that you will leave Canada at the end of your visit
> - have enough money for your stay. The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
> - You may also need a medical exam and letter of invitation from someone who lives in Canada.
>
> Some people are not admissible to Canada, which means they are not allowed to enter the country. You can be inadmissible for several reasons, including being involved in:
>
> criminal activity
> human rights violations
> organized crime
> You can also be inadmissible for security, health or financial reasons. Find out more about inadmissibility.

=====

Good luck and welcome if you get through!!

Comment: Nice answer. Is any of the content quoted verbatim? If so, could you please i) link to the actual page where the quote come from ii) use the markdown quote environment to highlight the quote (i.e. put `> ` before the quoted text.

Comment: Considering the number of questions exactly like this for Canada, this could be polished and elevated to a canonical I think.